# Play framework Change Config file value in Stand Alone distribution

Tags: playframework, config, production, playframework-2.4

I have a Play 2.4 application that will be used mainly in a local network and will be deployed using the `.bat` file generated from the dist command (in a Windows environment). There is a file path stored in the config file that needs to be changed by editing the config file. But I have learned that the conf file in the distribution doesn't get read when application starts, but a pre compiled one.
In other words I need to make changes in the conf file and reflect those changes in the next application lunch.

I tried alternative conf files in play documentation, but couldn't make it work due to Error `Bad application path Dconfig.file=/path/"`

How can I make my edited conf file to be loaded each time application starts?

Any thought will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you have 'packaged' your application with the `dist` command, you are still free to provide a new config file:

`$ my-first-app-1.0/bin/my-first-app -Dconfig.file=/full/path/to/conf/application-prod.conf`